# PowerShell script to amend certain lines in a text file

Tags: powershell

I've got this script, which is supposed to open the ini file and change the line that starts with "ProjectPath=". It opens the file fine, reads the data, goes through each line, modifies the needed line in $line, but the $lines stays the same, so the output file gets written, but with unchanged data. What am I missing? Any help would be much appreciated as I've already spent hours on it.

```
# Get the file content as an array of lines
$lines = Get-Content "C:\TEMP\test.ini"

# Loop through the lines
foreach ($line in $lines) {
        if ($line.StartsWith("ProjectPath=")) {
        # Replace the line with the new value
        $line = "ProjectPath=%USERPROFILE%\Documents"
    }
}
# Write the modified lines back to the file
Set-Content "C:\TEMP\test.ini" $lines -Force
```

Nothing that I tried has helped.

Answer (score 3):

- As a general rule, *assigning to* the self-chosen iterator variable in a  [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) statement (`$line = ...`, in your case) has *no effect on the collection being enumerated* - doing so simply updates the iterator variable in that iteration (and if you do not otherwise use this updated variable, the assignment is a *no-op*).
- Instead of attempting *in-place updating*, you can use the *pipeline* to *output* the - conditionally modified - lines, using the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) *cmdlet*, which allows you to directly pipe them to [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content):

```bash
(Get-Content 'C:\TEMP\test.ini') | # Note the required (...) enclosure
  ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.StartsWith('ProjectPath=')) {
      'ProjectPath=%USERPROFILE%\Documents' # Replace the original line with this.
    } else { 
      $_ # Pass the original line through.
    }
  } |
  Set-Content 'C:\TEMP\test.ini' -Force
```

Note:

- In the script block passed to `ForEach-Object`, the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) refers to the input object (line, in this case) at hand.
- Note how the [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) call is enclosed in `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--), which ensures that the lines of the input file are read *in full, up front*, which is what allows writing back to that file as part of the same pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable, updating `$line` will simply re-assign a new string to that variable, will not mutate the item in `$lines` (the array of strings).

You can change the logic a little bit then it should work:

```bash
$lines = foreach ($line in Get-Content 'C:\TEMP\test.ini') {
    if ($line.StartsWith("ProjectPath=")) {
        "ProjectPath=%USERPROFILE%\Documents"
        continue
    }

    $line
}
# Write the modified lines back to the file
Set-Content "C:\TEMP\test.ini" $lines -Force
```

Be aware, `.StartsWith` is case-sensitive. You can target the `StringComparison` overload if you need it to be case-insensitive

```bash
$line.StartsWith('ProjectPath=', [System.StringComparison]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not to take away from the other answers, but to provide an alternative method, here's a cool way to do it reading the contents of a file using the `${...}` notation:

```bash
${C:\TEMP\test.ini} -replace '^ProjectPath=.+','ProjectPath=%USERPROFILE%\Documents' | 
    Set-Content -Path "C:\TEMP\test.ini" -Force
```

When you use this notation, PowerShell uses the path as the variable name, treating the file content as the value of the variable. It's a special feature of PowerShell, and it's unique in terms of language design.

- The `-Replace` handles the actual line replacement with the `^` anchor for the condition of the line beginning with that string.

However, this feature can be less well-known or intuitive for users. While it provides a concise way to read file contents, it might be less readable to someone unfamiliar with this notation. This is especially true in scripts that others might read or maintain, it's generally recommended to use the more explicit `Get-Content` cmdlet - *as you currently are*.

---

As for your question on why it never updated, and as others have pointed out, `$line` was the only change in your script while it held no real reference to `$lines`.

**Note**: *this is simply a unique solution I figured I'd share.*

Answer (score 0):

To complement the helpful answers from [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) and [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon), *properties* of an object are usual "by reference" and therefore mutable (replaceable) by itself.
Despite I am usual advocating the [PowerShell pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines), in this case you might avoid it and use a [`for`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_for) loop instead because you will need to choke it anyways as explained by mklement0's "[`(...)` enclosure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77199205/1701026)" note.

```
(Get-Content 'C:\TEMP\test.ini') | # Note mklement0's (...) enclosure
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Lines.Count; $i++) { 
    if ($lines[$i].StartsWith("ProjectPath=")) {
        # Replace the line with the new value
        $lines[$i] = "ProjectPath=%USERPROFILE%\Documents"
    }
}
Set-Content 'C:\TEMP\test.ini' $lines -Force
```